# Gremlin Tinkerpop get vertex with partial ID

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

Is there a way to get a vertex with only a partial ID? For example, let's say I have two unique values that make up part of the ID, such as: `employeeName/{employeeName}/dob/{employeeDoB}`.

If I only have ONE of the values, such as `employeeName`, can I still get the vertex by just knowing that part?

I was thinking I could use the Tinkerpop `Text` enum and do something like:

```
g.V("employeeName/" + id, Text.startingWith);
```

But I get a serialization error with that:

```
- it could not be sent to the server - Reason: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.io.IOException: Serializer for type org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Text$3 not found
```

Using Tinkerpop 3.5.1 with Amazon Neptune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `TextP` and not `Text`, and you also need to add a filtering step. So it becomes:

```java
g.V().hasId(TextP.startingWith("employeeName/" + name));
```

This assumes you are sending the request from Java. In a large graph this may not be efficient, and you may want to consider looking at the OpenSearch/ElasticSearch Full Text Search (FTS) integration.